# The loop runs, The (Modoule) in if else than it gives me error

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement

[[This image does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9rb6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1bYT.png)

```java
public class file {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
for (double i = 1; i < 50; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    double x = 1000;
    x = (x/i);
    System.out.println(x);
    if(x % 2){
        System.out.println("The number is even" + x);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The number is odd" + x);
    }
}}}

The number is even1.2765957446808507 48.0
20.833333333333332
The number is even0.8333333 33333321
49.0
20.408163265306122
The number is even0.408163265306122 PS C:\Users\Amrit>
& 'C:\Users\Amrit\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\j dk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-c
p' 'C:\Users\Amrit\AppData\Local\Temp\vscodesws_db8f8\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-projec t\bin'
'file'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to boolean
at file.main(file.java:9)
PS C:\Users\Amrit> ||
```

[Text courtesy of imagetotext.info](https://www.imagetotext.info/)

The loop works for me, but when I try to add (Modoule) in if else than it gives me error. I was expecting to run if and else and give me even odd numbers

Comment: `x % 2` returns a number, but an *if* condition is required to be a `boolean`. Note that in Java, a number is not automatically converted to a boolean.

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of your code. Instead, post the code itself.

Comment: `if(x % 2){` should be `if(x % 2 == 0){` Java has strong types. Unlike C.

Comment: @user16320675 fixed. I think that was an OCR error. OP really shouldn't be using pics to show code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(x % 2){
```

Doesn't work because `x` is a double and so `x % 2` isn't the boolean the `if` expected. Unlike c, java wont convert that for you.

```
if (x % 2 == 0) {
```

Will work but it sets my teeth on edge because most of the time you shouldn't test a double's equality since they are used for lossy things like measurements. Typically you test them to be less then some epsilon value. Only good excuse I've ever thought of is to test if it was loaded or saved correctly.

Modular division is more typically used on integers anyway.

Oh and fix your indentation so the end of your code doesn't look like an ugly fish gill.